# Reversing a sub-array of an array , in less than O(n) time

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linked-list, reverse

how can we reverse a subarray ( say from i-th index to j-th index ) of an array ( or any other data structure , like linked-list ( not doubly )), in less than O(n) time ? the O(n) time consumption is trivial.( I want to do this reversion many times on the array , like starting from the beginning and reversing it for n times (each time , going forward for one index and then reversing it again), so there should be a way ,which its amortized analysis would give us a time consumption less than O(n) , any idea ?
thanks In advance :)

Comment: Yes , but I didn't ask for the code , and actually i did it by O(n), searching for better solutions out of curiosity :) guess that's okay,isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah, it's no problem to ask, but homework tasks should be tagged as such.

Comment: What is the end-goal that you are trying to achieve with all this reversing? Don't put us in a "box", and we'll have a better chance of doing some out-of-box thinking ;)

Comment: @Branko:It's really a long task , believe me what i asked is not even close to what i have to do at all :( i just wanted to have an improvement in the time consumption of my final algorithm, which uses this task ( reversing )in order to operate.

Comment: Found solution with O(1) look for my answer at [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/216217/104450)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to solve this with a wrong approach. I guess you want to improve the algorithm as a whole, and not the O(n) reversing stuff. Because that's not possible. You always have O(n) if you have to consider each of the n elements.

As I said, what you can do is improve the O(n^2) algorithm. You can solve that in O(n):
Let's say we have this list:

```
a b c d e
```

You then modify this list using your algorithm:

```
e d c b a
e a b c d
```

and so on.. in the end you have this:

```
e a d b c
```

You can get this list if you have two pointers coming from both ends of the array and alternate between the pointers (increment/decrement/get value). Which gives you O(n) for the whole procedure.

More detailed explanation of this algorithm:

Using the previous list, we want the elements in the follow order:

```
a b c d e
2 4 5 3 1
```

So you create two pointers. One pointing at the beginning of the list, the other one at the end:

```
a b c d e
^       ^
p1      p2
```

Then the algorithms works as follows:

```
1. Take the value of p2
2. Take the value of p1
3. Move the pointer p2 one index back
4. Move the pointer p1 one index further
5. If they point to the same location, take the value of p1 and stop.
   or if p1 has passed p2 then stop.
   or else go to 1.
```

Comment: :Yeah ,improving the O(n^2) algorithm is what im after , but can u explain a little more on what is alternating between pointers ? Thanks

Comment: wow , Impressed :) it's just the algorithm i was trying to get to , thanks man for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it O(n) time for given array. Here l represents starting index and r represents end. So we need to reverse subarray from r to l.

```
public void reverse(int[] arr, int l, int r)
  {
      int d = (r-l+1)/2;
      for(int i=0;i<d;i++)
      {
         int t = arr[l+i];
         arr[l+i] = arr[r-i];
         arr[r-i] = t;
      }
    // print array here 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As duedl0r mentioned, O(n) is your minimum. you will have to move n items to their new position.

Since you mentioned a linked list, here's an O(n) solution for that.

If you move through all nodes and reverse their direction, then tie the ends to the rest of the list, the sublist is reversed. So:

```
1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->9
```

reversing 4 through 7 would change:

```
4->5->6->7
```

into:

```
4<-5<-6<-7
```

Then just let 3 point to 7 and let 4 point to 8.

Somewhat copying duedl0r's format for consistency:

```
 1. Move to the item before the first item to reorder(n steps)
 2. remember it as a (1 step)
 3. Move to the next item (1 step)
 4. Remember it as b (1 step)

while not at the last item to reorder: (m times)
 5. Remember current item as c (1 step)
 6. Go to next item (1 step)
 7. Let the next item point to the previous item (1 step)

having reached the last item to reorder:
 8. let item a point to item c (1 step)

if there is a next item:
 9. move to next item (1 step)
 10. let item b point to current item (1 step)
```

That's O(n+1+1+1+m*(1+1+1)+1+1+1).
Without all the numbers that aren't allowed in Big O, that's O(n+m), which may be called O(n+n), which may be called O(2n).

And that's O(n).